# "Who's been waiting" vs "Who've been waiting"

Tags: grammar, be, have

Which form of this phrase is correct?

> for everyone who's been waiting

or

> for everyone who've been waiting

I've heard "who's" used more often in this context but "who have" sounds more correct than "who is" in this phrase. 
However, "to be" in a state of waiting seems more logical than "to have" a state of waiting, unless it works like *Tener* in Spanish.

Comment: "who's been waiting" is a contraction of "who has been waiting," not of "who is been waiting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would it be if you dropped the *for/who* from it?  You would end up with:

> everyone has been waiting

and

> everyone have been waiting

Some [indefinite pronouns](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/indefinite-pronouns/), including *everyone*, are always singular, even if they refer to multiple people.  So in this case, *everyone has* is correct.  That means that

> for everyone who's been waiting

is correct.  (The verb goes with *everyone* not *who*.)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of "who's" it would be "who has" and not "who is" - For everyone who has been waiting.

The use case for "who've" would be "For those who've been waiting...."